# Using Constant Type Sizes vs Using Thresholds on Sizes

Tags: c, memory, types

In cases where defining a `struct` with types of platform/implementation-dependent type sizes, some types may be too large for the purpose of the struct.
For example: the `struct` will be spawned a million times and having too large types take up memory is unacceptable.

Is there a common way of ensuring the type will be, say, < 8 bytes?

I know that using types that are (almost) always *n* bytes in size will solve this, but what if I need to use something like `size_t` and keep it under 8 bytes? (In the sense that the type and its usage would have precedence over size)

Is there any other way of accomplishing this, such as preprocessor magic or something among the lines of:

```
#if (sizeof(type)>8)
  struct { otherType a; }
#else
  struct { type a; }
#endif
```

All I've found on the code above are assertions, which will just cause an error.

Is there a correct way of doing this and why?

Comment: And what are these types? Why not just use `uint64_t` say?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm totally okay with using a set-size type, but I was wondering if there was a more dynamic solution. In the case of `size_t` since it has no upper limit, its implementation varies and I was wondering if there would be a way to change it to an `int`, for example, if it were too large.

Comment: Well, if `size_t` is not big enough, then you cannot store all the sizes in your member. Of course you can compare `SIZE_MAX` say with `UINT64_MAX`...

Comment: I was referring to the size in bytes whenever I said "large", "small", etc.

Comment: Then the answer is "no". You can only expect that if `SIZE_MAX` is smaller or equal to `UINT64_MAX` that it would also be smaller or equal in bytes - might not be true, but that would be a very idiotic system.